# What does "Someone was wearing heavy black coats" mean?

Tags: meaning

- I came across a sentence "They were wearing heavy black coats" .  I
  want to know what 'heavy' means here. Does it mean the coat was heavy
  ( maybe the materials used to make the coat are of high density to
  make it thick enough to keep warm) ? Or does it mean the color of the
  coat was very dark?  And what about light grey jacet?  Is it talking
  about the color or the weight ? THanks .

---

Comment: MIB HC - Men in black heavy coats.

Comment: The opposite of "light" in the colour "light grey" is "dark grey", not "heavy grey". The opposite of "light" in "light jacket" is indeed "heavy jacket".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Heavy" in "heavy black coats" is a reference to the thickness of the fabric. It is not, for instance, a light windbreaker, it's made of a relatively sturdy fabric. There is not generally a "heavy black" color, though one might see it in literary contexts.

The "light" in "light gray jacket," however, I would usually take to mean a jacket of unspecified weight in a light-gray color, unless context clearly indicated "light" was a fabric weight.

Comment: … or unless a comma separated the two adjectives: a light, grey jacket would be a grey jacket made of a light fabric, while a light-grey jacket would be a jacket of a light-grey colour, and a light grey jacket could be either, depending on context.

Comment: Correct, and a good real-life example of when punctuation matters.

Comment: We're lucky they weren't wearing *heavy light grey jackets*. Or, even worse, *light light grey jackets*.

Answer (score 0):

If I were writing that sentence and intended to use the word heavy in reference to the color, I would personally hyphenate it to become *heavy-black coat*. It would be even more necessary in light grey, seeing as "light" is a common word with which to define both color and coats, whereas I've never heard "heavy" being used for color.